# sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-7.0 runs fine, but no sdks are listed

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to run a C# project in VSCode on Ubuntu.  But VSC is telling me that I do not have .net installed.  One possibility is the SDK is not installed.  So I try to install it.

This command runs fine no error:

> sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-7.0

> dotnet --list-sdks
> Shows nothing at all

New Ubuntu install.  I've tries all the things on the MS site for the 100 ways to download .net sdk  no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the value of *DOTNET_ROOT* environment variable, and what `find / -iname dotnet -type f` outputs?

Comment: No env variable called DOTNET_ROOT
find returns:
/home/dlwiii/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime/.dotnet/7.0.14~x64/dotnet    
Just set DOTNET_ROOT=/usr/bin
   Same issue

Comment: what is the output of `which dotnet`? I have a feeling that you have multiple installations  of _dotnet_ cli. Try running _/home/dlwiii/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime/.dotnet/7.0.14~x64/dotnet --list-sdks_

Answer (score 0):

I install sdk on ubuntu 22 by following steps.

```
declare repo_version=$(if command -v lsb_release &> /dev/null; then lsb_release -r -s; else grep -oP '(?<=^VERSION_ID=).+' /etc/os-release | tr -d '"'; fi)
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$repo_version/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo apt update
apt install dotnet-sdk-8.0
```

[image]

You could try run the following codes before running above steps.

```
sudo snap remove dotnet-sdk
sudo apt remove 'dotnet*'
sudo apt remove 'aspnetcore*'
sudo apt remove 'netstandard*'
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list.save
sudo apt update
```

Comment: ok those commands worked, tho needed sudo on the apt-install dotnet-sdk-8.0  Still getting issues tho.  Will try some other things... alas, no sdks listed still